# Specificity of $n$ in $n\lambda=2\pi r$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

So I learnt that for constructive interference of electron's wave, its circumference should be equal to $n$ times its wavelength $\lambda$ where $n$ is the orbit number. But I wonder why $n$ is specifically the orbit number and not any integer as any integer would lead to constructive interference. Please help out and let me know if I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are completely right that $n$ can be any integer. However the [orbital angular momentum quantum number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_quantum_number) (also known as orbital quantum number or $l$) can also be any integer. There is thus no contradiction. The relation you found is actually the definition of the angular momentum quantum number.